# importing React component file with node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I have this node js application:

```
require('babel-register');
const router = require("./src/web/router");
```

and I am getting this error:

[image]

how can I import react component in node js?

Comment: Du you have a `.babelrc` file with the babel-preset-react added? If yes, please include it in your question. If not – that's the cause of the error.

Comment: It seems that you have imported the router properly but you are not parsing React's JSX

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov, this is absolutely the problem my friend, but how can I solve it?

Comment: @PatrickHund, this is my .babelrc: `{ presets: ["react"] }`

Comment: the fastest way is to run `npx create-react-app` enter the newly reacted directory and run `npm start` it will start example React application. Than you can move your existing code

Comment: for reference you can visit: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov, I want it to be a node.js app, without using CRA. (i am building a app that needs to read react files and do things with it)

Comment: In that case you will need to set-up a module bundler. Preferably `webpack`

Comment: I'd suggest you to go through Webpack's getting started page so you can learn to easily manga it. There are also ready set-ups in Github here is one which I found and looks promising: https://github.com/rwieruch/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup   (I haven't tested it)

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov, you know a way to do that without using webpack? (i know webpack, but i don't want to use it)

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov you don't necessarily need to use webpack to use Babel (although it does help a lot)

Comment: @PatrickHund Yes, I know. You don't even need Babel at all nor nodeJS, webpack and so on. You can create React application straight into your browser using only `react.js`   I am just not sure what exactly @NirBerko is trying to achieve and I'm busy right now

Comment: @NedkoDimitrovI am trying to build a package that takes react routes and build a sitemap from them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible using esm node pacakge, esm is a fast, production ready, zero-dependency ES module loader for Node 6+.

[esm on github](https://github.com/standard-things/esm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in server side rendering your react component I made a small library that makes it easy to render react components from a node application https://github.com/tswayne/react-helper#getting-started.  If you are trying to server side render, or import the react component for any other reason, you will need to compile your server side code with babel or use something like [babel-node](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-node) to compile at runtime.