# How to import .jsx files to .js files in reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

I m using node.js for this and using react as frontend, Now how do I import app.jsx file to index.js file?
index.js

```
import App from "./components/app";

ReactDOM.render(<App text="Hello world"/> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

app.jsx

```
function App(props){
    return <h1>{props.text}</h1>
}

export default App;
```

now at last in app.jsx file I tried to import/require the React file but I get an error "require is not defined"

also in console when importing app.jsx it says require is not defined
i m using import and that's what it says

Comment: try adding the filetype in the import statement  import App from "./components/App.jsx";

Comment: Does this answer your question? [importing React component file with node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54003260/importing-react-component-file-with-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `npx create-react-app` in your terminal to create new starter react app, you will see the working code over there.
link for more info https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

Comment: i m not talking about react app, i want a backend with reactjs as frontend

Answer (score 1):

if there is "type":"module" in package.json, remove it.

Comment: there is no "type" module

Comment: I guess it might be a problem in node. Does the error occur other project file? or just in this project?

Comment: This is my 1st project with node react

Comment: If i create a react app, i cant create different routes, cant get data from mongoose

Answer (score 0):

Did you type code below at the top in index.js and app.jsx file?

```
// app.jsx
import React from "react";

// index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
```

or maybe you type "require" code in the wrong line. Check it!

Comment: whenever i type import a error comes saying that require Is not defined, but this code works for me ```ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: my problem is i cant import anything